# Child menu items not displayed in drupal

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I've a sub-menu like this:

[image]

I'm trying to build a custom theme, I just copied which contains following code:

```
<?php if ($main_menu || $secondary_menu): ?>
  <div id="navigation"><div class="section">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Main menu'))); ?>
    <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array('links' => $secondary_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'secondary-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Secondary menu'))); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#navigation -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**This is how its being displayed:** Note that not even the HTML for child menu items are generated.
[image: http://i.snag.gy/0yAdk.jpg]

Yes, I've *Show as expanded* option checked for "Publications".

PS:
Why does drupal make even such simple things difficult. No wonder, its losing ground to wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$menu_name = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
$tree = menu_tree($menu_name);
print drupal_render($tree);
?>
```

Also Drupal doesn't make things hard, you just don't understand it yet.

It is just a tool suited to specific tasks. If you just want to make a blog then don't use Drupal, just use Wordpress.

If however you want a very powerful CMF (Content management framework, not system) to create complex systems with lots of inter-related entities then continue to learn Drupal - I think it's the best tool for the job.

Comment: Hi I was aware of this method of displaying (copied it from another theme), but I didn't want to use it because, I wanted to add custom 'css classes' to `<ul>` & `<li>` elements

Comment: You can still theme your menu. This this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317462/drupal-override-custom-menu-template